# How to set headers in HTTPS get request?

Tags: javascript, https, get, noaa

I'm using [npm package https](https://www.npmjs.com/package/https) by hardus to make get requests to NOAA. Documentation on [NOAA](https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/webservices/v2#data) is poor and on the https package is non-existent, and I am having trouble setting a header. Here is my code for my requests,

```html
https.get(url, function(res) {
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', (chunk) => {
    //Parse through and deal with data...
  }
  res.on('error', (e) => {
    //Deal with error...
  }
}
```

How can I add a header to my request to include the Web Service Token?

Comment: As an aside, if you're looking for a more robust and well-known `npm` package with good documentation, [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) may be what you're looking for!

Comment: `https` is an empty package, you're actually using the standard [`https` module](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html).